# rails-api testing post request --> undefined 'to_i error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, post, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I have a [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) app built by doing: `rails-api new myapp --skip-sprockets -d mysql`

Then I have some content that I created using: `rails g scaffold data name:string`

I'm having issues testing post requests to create objects of that type, using rails default testing tool. I'm getting:

```
undefined method `to_i' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)
```

My routes are setup: `resources :data, except: [:new, :edit]`
Controllers & model have been generated as usual by `rails g scaffold`

Details:
- Ruby 2.1.1
- Rails 4
- data_controller.rb: https://gist.github.com/glesage/9902677
- data_controller_test.rb: https://gist.github.com/glesage/9902719
- Stack for error with turn: https://gist.github.com/glesage/9903392
- Stack for error without turn: https://gist.github.com/glesage/9903413
- Stack for error with artmees's way: https://gist.github.com/glesage/9903483
*

Please advise! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

i think you are missing the request headers for the api

```
test "should create data" do
  assert_difference('Data.count') do
    post '/data',             # URL to the data
      { name: 'my_name' },    # params you want to send
      {                       # Headers make sure they are correct don't just copy them
        HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/json', # This is cause i send the request in JSON
        HTTP_ACCEPT: 'application/vnd.your_domain+json; version=1'
      }
  end

  assert_response 201
end
```

Comment: Uhm I don't think that is it. When I append this I then get an error on the last close bracket: `syntax error, unexpected '\n'`

Comment: i've edited the answer, check it... i prefer using this format where the `post '/url', { param: value, param2: value2}, { Header: value}`

Comment: Thanks alot... but unfortunately I still get the `"undefined method` `to_i'` `for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)"` error ):

Comment: could you put the controller implementation ?

Comment: could you add the full stack of the error... what lines caused it ? and the `routes.rb` file ?

Comment: It turns out that error is specific to the turn gem /: Here's the stack: https://gist.github.com/glesage/9903392

Comment: If I run it without turn I get a different error: https://gist.github.com/glesage/9903413

Answer (score 0):

I think this ended up being a non-error. http://rubygems.org/gems/turn possibly is not compatible with API style JSON post requests, amongts other things.

Without using turn I was able to diagnose the problem better, tracing it back to the 'sanitize_for_mass_assignment' Rails 4 problem, as well as the controller requiring different parameters than passed...

Weird stuff (:

Thanks artmees for the help anyways!